# maven inside kubernetes gets "connection timeout" from central repository

Tags: maven, docker, kubernetes

I'm running maven in a docker on a kubernetes cluster. While fetching dependencies, it sometimes hangs for up to 2 hours, logging several `connection timeout` errors before it finally succeed.

```
[11:34:31] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/path/to/internal/artifact-20181129.112650-1.pom
[11:50:15] :     [Step 1/2] Nov 29, 2018 11:50:15 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
[11:50:15] :     [Step 1/2] INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://repo1.maven.org:80: Connection timed out (Read failed)
[11:50:15] :     [Step 1/2] Nov 29, 2018 11:50:15 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
[11:50:15] :     [Step 1/2] INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://repo1.maven.org:80
[12:05:59] :     [Step 1/2] Nov 29, 2018 12:05:59 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
[12:05:59] :     [Step 1/2] INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://repo1.maven.org:80: Connection timed out (Read failed)
[12:05:59] :     [Step 1/2] Nov 29, 2018 12:05:59 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
[12:05:59] :     [Step 1/2] INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://repo1.maven.org:80
[12:21:44] :     [Step 1/2] Nov 29, 2018 12:21:44 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
[12:21:44] :     [Step 1/2] INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://repo1.maven.org:80: Connection timed out (Read failed)
[12:21:44] :     [Step 1/2] Nov 29, 2018 12:21:44 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
[12:21:44] :     [Step 1/2] INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://repo1.maven.org:80
[12:37:28] :     [Step 1/2] [INFO] Downloading: http://nexus/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/com/path/to/internal/artifact-20181129.112650-1.pom
```

This only happens for internal dependencies that should immediately fall back to our internal nexus maven repository which is also inside the kubernetes cluster.

A tcpdump during such hang shows only re-transmissions, without response from the central repo. other than that, the capture is filled with ARP queries until finally, the fallback happens and it queries our internal Nexus server.

[wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR7Bh.png)

Here's the relevant section of my pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>thirdparty</id>
    <name>internal third party repo</name>
    <url>${nexusUrl}/repositories/thirdparty</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>releases</id>
    <name>internal releases repo</name>
    <url>${nexusUrl}/repositories/releases</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>snapshots</id>
    <name>internal snapshots repo</name>
    <url>${nexusUrl}/repositories/snapshots</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
    </releases>
    <id>license4j-runtime-library</id>
    <name>License4J Runtime Library Maven Repository</name>
    <url>https://www.license4j.com/maven/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

And here's my settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<localRepository/>
<interactiveMode/>
<usePluginRegistry/>
<offline/>
<pluginGroups/>
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>releases</id>
        <username>XXX</username>
        <password>YYY</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <username>XXX</username>
        <password>YYY</password>
    </server>
</servers>
<mirrors/>
<proxies/>
<profiles/>
<activeProfiles/>
```

This happens every once in while and I can't find the root cause. I hope someone has ran into this somewhere.

Comment: Could you add more information about maven settings: which parameters do you use, what is in pom.xml and in maven default settings for repositories?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev I added settings and pom xml details. Is this enough?

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. It's been more than 5 years since you asked this question. Have you managed to circumvent the problem by any chance?